# How to push array value with defined object in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, foreach

***My array***

```
let myArr=["test1","test2"];
```

***Need to add the object like below***

```
let myFinalArr=[["test1":{"val1":"XXX","val2":"YYY"}],["test2":{"val1":"XXX","val2":"YYY"}]];
```

how to push the data like above in angular.

Comment: Can you please be more clear. what do you want to add and what should with the old data happen and what have you DONE and what is the problem

Comment: The output you're asking for is wrong. There is no such thing as `["test1":{"val1":"XXX","val2":"YYY"}]`. Do you require `{"test1":{"val1":"XXX","val2":"YYY"},"test2":{"val1":"XXX","val2":"YYY"}}`?

Comment: this.casted_values.forEach((cas_val,index)=>{
  this.seriesConfig.push(cas_val:{val1:"xxx",val2:"yyy"})
})

Comment: @MichaelD, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. How exactly does the requirement look? Does the object remain same for all the elements in the array?

And expanding from your comment that the following is the actual output's structure

```js
{
  "test1": { "val1":"XXX", "val2":"YYY" },
  "test2": { "val1":"XXX", "val2":"YYY" }
}
```

You could try the `Array#reduce` with spread operator to transform the array

```js
let myArr = ["test1", "test2"];

const output = myArr.reduce((acc, curr) => ({
  ...acc,
  [curr]: { val1: "XXX", val2: "YYY" }
}), Object.create(null));

console.log(output);
```